# Nodejs - Error using properties-reader package

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties-file

I am trying to write a generic properties reader utility using `properties-reader` package of `nodejs`. Following is implementation:

```
var propertiesReader = require('properties-reader')
var path = require('path')

var property = getPropertyFile('./fileName.properties');
console.log(getProperty(property,'user1.username'))

function getPropertyFile(err, filePath){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error occured while reading properties file: "err);
    }
    else{
        return propertiesReader(filePath);
    }
}

function getProperty(err, propertyFile, propertyName){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error occured while getting properties: ",err);
    }
    else{
        return propertyFile.get(propertyName)
    }   
}
```

on executing above code I am getting error in reading file and getting property value as below:

```
E:\NodeJS\>node propertiesUtility.js
Error occured while reading properties file:  ./locatorValues.properties
E:\NodeJS\propertiesUtility.js:24
                return propertyFile.get(propertyName)
                                    ^

TypeError: propertyFile.get is not a function
    at getProperty (E:\NodeJS\propertiesUtility.js:24:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\NodeJS\propertiesUtility.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

Can someone please help me in correcting my code.

Comment: thats because you are passing a string and trying to access a method on that string that does not exist

Comment: The file exist in the system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some change like below and it worked:

```
function getValueFromPropertyFile (filePath, propertyName){
        try{
            property = propertiesreader(filePath)
            return property.get(propertyName)
        }
        catch(e){
            if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') {
                throw e
            } else {
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing a `'user1.username'` which is a plain String to `getProperty(err, propertyFile, propertyName)`, now  propertyFile is a plain string

```
'user1.username'.get(propertyName);
```

unless you have added the method get() to the string prototype, that method does not exist.

Comment: I have updated the code. It is not able to read properties file. hence cannot use get method

Comment: you are calling your code up top like console.log(getProperty(property,'user1.username')) now function getProperty(err, propertyFile, propertyName) will be called, now propertyName has 'user1.username' which is a plain string. The String type does not have a method called get()

Comment: Is there anyway I can handle this. I need to pass many properties file and read many properties hence I need a utility so that I dont have to repeat code.